# PostgreSQL is refusing connections from MapServer

Tags: postgis, postgresql, mapserver

I have MapServer 6.04 running in CentOS 6.7.  I am able to serve shapefiles and GeoJSON, but when I try to connect to a PostGIS (2.1.8)  enabled PostgreSQL (9.4.5) database it fails with the error: `Database connection failed`. I can connect to the database via QGIS and python from other machines. I can also run `ogrinfo PG:"user=radar dbname=radar" ktlx -summary` and get the following output:

```
Layer name: ktlx  
Geometry: 3D Multi Polygon  
Feature Count: 6  
Extent: (-98.807300, 32.737200) - (-93.488900, 36.542300)  
Layer SRS WKT:  
GEOGCS["NAD83",  
DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",  
    SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,  
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],  
    TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],  
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],  
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,  
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],  
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,  
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],  
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]]
FID Column = index  
Geometry Column = geom  
radar: String (0.0)  
val: Integer (3.0)
```

The connection info in my .map file is:

```
CONNECTIONTYPE postgis
CONNECTION "host=127.0.0.1 dbname=radar user=radar"
```

Every reference I have found in the documentation indicates that the the `CONNECTIONTYPE` and `CONNECTION` strings I am using are correct.  Is there a different connection string to use?

Comment: pg_hba.conf needs to accept connections even localhost see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278379/how-to-configure-postgresql-to-accept-all-incoming-connections

Comment: If the question title was "PostgreSQL is refusing connections from MapServer" you'd be a whole lot closer to solving the problem.

Comment: have you tried it with "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1"?  I also would try to set a password and use it.

Comment: The pg_hba.conf file is set to receive connection from localhost as well as 127.0.01.   I tried localhost, with and without a password, with md5 and trust. None of them work, but they all work with ogrinfo command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one last check I set selinux to Permissive and was able to connect.  This is not how I want to leave it, so now to the selinux logs to get the proper context for apache and map server.